# Generating permutations of specific characters only, within a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, permutation

The code generates all permutations/combinations of a string, where certain characters are permuted with others in its similar list. Currently, the code breaks because it doesn't keep its output within the list and so breaks with duplicates. For example we should get: `generatePerms('food') = ['food', 'fo0d','f0od','f00d']` but we instead get `['food', 'fo0d','f0od']`. How can I fix my code?

```
def generatePerms(newDomain):
    permutations = []
    similarities = [
                    ['i','l','!','|'],
                    ['o','0'],
                    ['e','3'],
                   ]

    for i in range(len(newDomain)):
        for similarList in similarities:
            if newDomain[i] in similarList:
                #get the substrings around the similar char
                start = newDomain[0:i]
                end = newDomain[i+1:]
                #concatenate the different possible characters and add to global list
                for chars in similarList:
                    permutations.append(start+chars+end) 
              
    return list(set(permutations))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the existing approach is that after you compute, say, `"f0od"` as being a permutation, you need to add it to the pool for future transformations to be applied to. In other words, for a given index, the original word is being considered, but you want to consider both the original word as well as any previous "permutations" you've generated.

The operation you're looking for here is more of a Cartesian product than a permutation--for each special character, you want to pick every character it could take on, then find every other choice for special characters in the rest of the string. This is basically a nested loop without writing it explicitly. [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does exactly this, along with some extra bookkeeping work to locate and modify only the special indices:

```
from itertools import product

def product_of_similar_chars(s, similarities):
    sims = {x: y for y in similarities for x in y}
    idxes = [i for i, x in enumerate(s) if x in sims]
    pools = [sims[x] for i, x in enumerate(s) if i in idxes]

    for arrangement in product(*pools):
        L = list(s)

        for i, x in zip(idxes, arrangement):
            L[i] = x

        yield "".join(L)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    similarities = [
        ["i", "l", "!", "|"],
        ["o", "0"],
        ["e", "3"],
    ]

    tests = ["food", "ego", "3|", "ei0", "lie"]

    for test in tests:
        print(list(product_of_similar_chars(test, similarities)))
```

Output:

```
['food', 'fo0d', 'f0od', 'f00d']
['ego', 'eg0', '3go', '3g0']
['ei', 'el', 'e!', 'e|', '3i', '3l', '3!', '3|']
['eio', 'ei0', 'elo', 'el0', 'e!o', 'e!0', 'e|o', 
 'e|0', '3io', '3i0', '3lo', '3l0', '3!o', '3!0', 
 '3|o', '3|0']
['iie', 'ii3', 'ile', 'il3', 'i!e', 'i!3', 'i|e', 
 'i|3', 'lie', 'li3', 'lle', 'll3', 'l!e', 'l!3', 
 'l|e', 'l|3', '!ie', '!i3', '!le', '!l3', '!!e', 
 '!!3', '!|e', '!|3', '|ie', '|i3', '|le', '|l3', 
 '|!e', '|!3', '||e', '||3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use itertools.combinations_with_replacement, which will generate all combinations of a specified length, even if they are duplicate, which means that it generate all combinations of all lenghts (except the empty one). Example:

```py
import itertools

def generate_perms(s):
    l = [s]

    positions = [i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i] == 'o']
    for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(positions, len(positions)):
        s2 = list(s)
        for i in c:
            s2[i] = '0'
        l.append(''.join(s2))

    return set(l)
```

This code produces the following result:

```py
>>> generate_perms('food')
{'food', 'f00d', 'fo0d', 'f0od'}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Seems like a reasonable start but can you generalize this to work on accepting a 2d list as input and with strings that may be more complex than simply `'o'` swapping with `'0'`?

Comment: Thank you! I don't think this is necessary considering the author's question was specifically focused on this part of the code. Feel free to edit my answer and do it though, but I think this could alter the clarity of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the invite but edits should adhere to author's intent, so I'll leave it up to you to adjust if you see fit.